# Enabling jframe from another jframe

Tags: java, jframe, awt

Hy. I have problem when my first jframe button was set disable the frame then log on to another jframe.
Jframe1 , my code:

```
Private void.jbutton1actionperformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
this.setEnabled(false);
new Jframe2().show();
}
```

I'm not make Jframe1 dispose, only disabled, and make Jframe2 showing. In Jframe2  I set button here:

```
Private void jbutton1actionperformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
this.dispose()
new Jframe1().setEnabled(true);
}
```

Then my problem is, Jframe1 was still disabled. I dont know how to make enable from another jframe. Please help me!

Comment: Don't use the show() method. You should be using `setVsiible(true)`.

Comment: Yes, I'll try use setVisible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you use `new` that means you are creating a new jFrame1, not updating the old one.

Comment: Thank before. So what I must to do make enabling Jframe1 from button in Jftame2?

Comment: I suggest to use this.setVisible(true) then using this.setEnabled(false) when u want to hide the jframe and this.setVisible(false) when you want to show the jframe

Comment: Thank you so much belabed. I'll try your suggest.